# Apache reverse proxy with LDAP check on client certificate cn

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, reverse-proxy

Apache version 2.4.29,
Windows Server 2012 R2

Just started and is very new to working with Apache. I am using Apache as a forward and reverse proxy for application to application SOAP communication. I have the connection setup with SSL mutual authentication. Currently trying to setup on the reverse proxy a way to check the client certificate cn against the LDAP directory, but I am having problems getting it to work.

The C# client application that I made works in making the connection to the service behind the proxy, but once I add in the LDAP configuration changes in the httpd-ssl file, the client app returns an error: "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="ApacheProxy"'."

Below is the configuration I'm using. Maybe there is something I am missing or doing incorrectly?  I'm not so confident this can accomplish what I am aiming for.

```
 <Location / > 

 AuthName "ApacheProxy" 
 AuthType Basic 
 AuthBasicProvider ldap 
 AuthLDAPURL "my_ldap_url" 
 AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=mycn,ou=applications,o=myo,c=myc" 
 AuthLDAPBindPassword mypassword 
 Require ldap-dn "cn=mycn,ou=applications,o=myo,c=myc" 
 LDAPReferrals Off 
 AuthLDAPCompareDNOnServer on 

 </Location>
```

When I try to navigate from my browser to the reverse proxy, it prompts for login. When I use my LDAP credentials, nothing happens, but by Wireshark I can see that my connection to LDAP was successful. I suspect I am having issues from my client application because of the login prompt. I would like to consult the community to see if there is a solution for doing an LDAP check on the client certificate cn without being prompted to login.

To summarize and word it differently, is there a way to automatically login to LDAP to check the cn of the client certificate when an application hits the Apache reverse proxy?

Comment: With `AuthType Basic` you configured basic authentication, that’s a pop up that asks for a username and password. If you want to use the client certificate to authenticate with,you’ll need to use the [`SSLVerifyClient`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) directive and more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply HBruijn.  I already have the SSL configurations setup and working.  I just want to also do a check on the client certificate cn to ensure that it is an application in the LDAP directory.  Is that possible to do in the Apache proxy?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1034538/86801 shows how to integrate MTLS with LDAP, just note that it uses the email attribute from the client certificate instead of the common name.